# Center Google Sign In Button

Tags: html, css, image, centering, google-signin

I know this sounds very simple and it could be, but I have been trying to center the button using margin: auto, text-align: center, and other methods and none have worked. I know you can customize the button, but I am fine with this button and just want to center it. 
[JSFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/jfjnxc52/3/)

```
   <html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="*******************.apps.googleusercontent.com">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,400">
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #37474f;
    }
    h1{
      color: white;
      font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
      font-weight: 500;

    }
    h3{
      color: white;
      font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
      font-weight: 100;

    }
    .center{
      margin-top: 10%;
      text-align:center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class='center'>
  <img src="https://www.nssc.org/images/design/register-icon.png" alt="Logo" style="max-width:100px; max-height:100px;">
  <h1>Email Database</h1>
  <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor.</h3>
  <br><br><br>
  <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="light" data-width="300" data-height="50" data-longtitle="true"></div>
  <!--<a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>-->
  <div>
  <script>
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
      // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
      var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
      console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
      console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
      console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
      console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
      console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
      console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

      // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
      var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          id_token: id_token
        },
        url: 'login_process.php',
        success: function(data) {
          //alert(data);
        }

      });
      //console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
    }

    function signOut() {
      var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      auth2.signOut().then(function() {
        console.log('User signed out.');
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where is the button?

Comment: It's this div ->  <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="light" data-width="300" data-height="50" data-longtitle="true"></div>

Comment: please create a jsfiddle the generated html button

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Put some text into your button and there you go! The `text-align` hack for centering will come into play.

Even if you place a button image there, it will work!

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnz5wqu5/)

```
  <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" 
      -theme="light" data-width="300" data-height="50"
      data-longtitle="true">button</div>
```

Don't know what the issue here is.

EDIT:

Solved it!

Use [this](https://jsfiddle.net/uvdx12hc)

```
.g-signin2{
  width: 100%;
}

.g-signin2 > div{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: The button wasn't showing in the old fiddle code. Now I updated it and am looking for the button to be centered.

Comment: check the new fiddle I added.. does it suffice?

Comment: The `g-signin-2` must be full-width and then when you have its child auto margin, the div gets center aligned

Comment: If you're using Vue, you will need to remove the `scoped` property from your style block in order to get this to work.

Comment: Yap. This works

Answer (score 5):

Simply add `margin: auto` to the container with the class `.abcRioButton`

```
.abcRioButton.abcRioButtonLightBlue { margin: 0 auto;}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/dL3uesrv/

Comment: Works very well as well! Thank you! What is the abcRioButton class? How did you figure it out? Just want to know to tackle future issues.

Comment: Just when you are inspecting an element, try to check its parent and how the layout is structured. Keep going up one level each time until you figure out which container should be adjusted.

Comment: This was the cat's meow.  Works great because I can't give the outer element a width because it changes after you sign in.  So, this little nugget is Totes McGoats.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`margin:auto` only works on fixed-width elements. You have a wrapper for your button which has margin:auto, but the width is only set on the child element. Put both rules onto one element and it will work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand. Could you edit some of the jsfiddle code if it doesn't take too long?